# Using loop and grep to deal with subfolders

Tags: arrays, loops, grep, subdirectory

Amid a bunch of subfolders, how do I enter only into those that contain a specific string (e.g. 1h2s) while looping through the array {1h2s,1kqf,...} and do grep? 
The full name of a subfolder consists "oligomerAngle-1h2s" OR 1kqf etc. plus a bunch of irregular numbers

Comment: ask question proper and clear way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use find:
`find . -type d -name \*1h2s\* -exec grep search {}/* \;`

`find .` search in current directory downwards
`-type d` means only find directories 
`-name \*1h2s\*` match only directories with this name (you need to escape the * from the shell)
`-exec grep search {}/* \;` run grep on each file in the found directories

NOTE: this will cause some error messages from grep if there are no files in the found directories or if there are sub-directories, you could add `2>/dev/null` to the command if you didn't want to see them

Comment: I tried this: 
find . -type d -name \*1h2s\* -exec grep -r -e "Distance" pairsAngles.txt {}/* \;
But only got a bunch of 
grep: pairsAngles.txt: No such file or directory
grep: ./oligomerAngle/oligomerAngle-1h2s-000_001-0003_0025_A-0034_0056_A-B004A012/*: No such file or directory
grep: pairsAngles.txt: No such file or directory
grep: ./oligomerAngle/oligomerAngle-1h2s-002_003-0070_0091_A-0095_0117_A-A004B009/*: No such file or directory
...

Comment: Finally solved w/ this line:
                         
find ~/aaPROJECT/helicalPair_ax/selectedPairs/renumberedPdb/clusterPairs-1.25-12-05_windows.12.resle3.2A.RMSD1.3/oligomerAngle/ -type d -name \*1h2s\* -exec grep "Distance" {}/pairsAngles.txt \; 

       :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this to work and also with multiple strings:

```
find ~/aaPROJECT/helicalPair_ax/selectedPairs/renumberedPdb/clusterPairs-1.25-12-05_windows.12.resle3.2A.RMSD1.3/oligomerAngle/ -type d -name \*1h2s\* -exec grep -E "Distance|Local angle|Average angle" {}/pairsAngles.txt \;
```

But wasn't able to output the results into a txt file after having tried all the existing solutions online... Well, that's another topic though.

Comment: is it not as simple as adding " >/path/to/output.file" to your command above?